# IE9 Developer Tools breaks my browser (causes some kind of loop)

Tags: internet-explorer-9, developer-tools

Whenever I try to use IE9 with developer tools, it causes the page to constantly refresh. See here: http://screencast.com/t/OgFVYvwhlg

When the Dev Tools window is open, the refresh starts to occur, and then when the window is closed, it stops.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to debug this?